# WordPress Loop Posts Which is Dont Have Featured Tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to loop posts which is dont have featured tag. I want this on main loop (query) which is have following codes :

```
if ( have_posts() ) :

     /* Start the Loop */
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

     endwhile;
endif;
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* The Query */
$tag = get_term_by('name', get_theme_mod('blog_filter_tag', ''), 'post_tag');
$args = array(
    'tag__not_in' => (int)$tag->term_id
);

query_posts( $args );
```

Solved i found solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You want to use the pre_get_posts filter to modify the main query. A taxonomy query can then be added to the main query args to filter it.

Are you using the built-in post tags to create a tag called featured, or are you setting the featured posts some other way? If you're just looking for posts that have a tag called featured, then the below code will show any posts that have been tagged with a tag called "featured".

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_main_query' );

function modify_main_query( $query ) {
    // Check if on frontend and this is the main query
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'post_tag',
                'terms'            => 'featured',
                'field'            => 'name',
                'operator'         => 'EXISTS',
                'include_children' => true,
            ),
        );

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i paste this codes on functions.php or index ?

Comment: And my main purpose is display posts which is dont have featured tag on main query

Comment: This goes inside of your functions.php file. If by display posts you mean the options inside of the format metabox, then you would need to change the taxonomy you're filtering by from `post_tag` to `post_format`.